# How to renew code within timeit scope?

Tags: python, scope, reload, timeit

This is what I'm doing:

```
In [9]: setup = '''
import my_module              
generator = my_module.any_func(1, 'two')
'''

In [10]: timeit.timeit('list(generator)', setup=setup, number=1000)
Out[10]: 4.6911962032318115
```

If I change `my_module` and run

```
In [11]: timeit.timeit('list(generator)', setup=setup, number=1000)
```

again, `timeit` don't recognize these changes. Currently I close `IPython` and do all this stuff again.

Is there a possibility to renew `timeit`'s scope? Something like `reload`?

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile I avoid a continual restart of a python shell with this "workaround":

```
>>> import my_module
>>> setup = '''
>>> from __main__ import my_module
>>> generator = my_module.any_func
>>> '''
```

By importing `my_module` in the `__main__` scope of the python shell and refer back to it within the `timeit` scope it is possible to reload changings within the `__main__` scope via

```
>>> reload(my_module)
```

Doing so `timeit` will use the reloaded module.

I've trying to do the `reload(my_module)` within `timeit`'s setup but this will raise a `NameError`. On the one hand it seems that `timeit`'s scope is permanent on the other hand accessing within this scope via `reload` is not possible. It's a kind of black magic…